# Populating ListView from Cursor in an "Activity"

Tags: android

```
public class MyNewTasks extends Activity{
 private DbAdapter_Task task;
 private DbAdapter_Assignment assignment;
 private DbAdapter_User user;
 LinearLayout linear;
 TextView text;
 ListView list;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String empid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("EmpID");

        assignment =  new DbAdapter_Assignment(getBaseContext());
        assignment.open();

        Cursor cursor = assignment.numOfNewTask(empid);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        linear = new LinearLayout(this); 
        linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 

        text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText(Html.fromHtml("<H1>" + "You have " + Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()) + " new assignments." + "</H1>"));

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.layout.listlayout);
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listlayout, cursor,         
                new String[] {"TaskID"}, new int[] { R.id.text});  
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        linear.addView(text);
        linear.addView(list);
        setContentView(linear);


 }
```

This is not populating list. What am I doing wrong ? I guess, It has to be a Activity not `ListActivity` as I have other views too.

listlayout.XML has ListView and listitem has textview (R.id.text)

Comment: check out your cursor size. Whether the cursor has the records or not?

Comment: Yes, it has. While debuging when it reaches SimpleCursorAdapter, it blows up.

Comment: instead of this "list=(ListView)findViewById(R.layout.listlayout);" use like this list=new ListView(this);

Comment: OK. How do I define listitem ?

Comment: oh u know...... SimpleCursorAdapter definition needs  "int" for list. I am not able to pass "list" that I created by using list=new ListView(this);

Comment: here int is  the ID of the chilview layout xml file.

Answer (score 0):

see the code bellow

```
Cursor cursor = assignment.numOfNewTask(empid);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    linear = new LinearLayout(this); 
    linear.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); 

    text = new TextView(this);
    text.setText(Html.fromHtml("<H1>" + "You have " + Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()) + " new assignments." + "</H1>"));

    list=new ListView(this);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitemlayout, cursor,         
            new String[] {"TaskID"}, new int[] { R.id.text});  
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    linear.addView(text);
    linear.addView(list);
    setContentView(linear);
```

see the constructor description of the [SimPleCurSorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29)

Comment: Thanks, it's working but not displaying anything. I am checking my cursor.

Comment: In that SimpleCursorAdapter, it is going to display all TaskID(Column name) in that R.id.text. Am I right ? Right now there is data in cursor and list is displaying empty.